# Database design for multiple hotel and multiple room?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

Suppose that I:

1. Own multiple hotels (say, 3)
2. Want to make a database about the rooms in those hotels.

So I have two tables in my database: hotels and rooms.

This the **hotel table**: (Owner #1 is me)

```
Hotel_ID(primary) | Hotel_Name | Owner_ID | Star |Phone | Info |
 1                     Java          1       3      ..     ..
 2                    Borobudur      1       5      ..     ..
 3                     Asia          1       1      ..     .. 
 4                    Wijaya         2       3      ..     ..
```

Thus, the **room table**, (I presume) will become like this:

```
Hotel_ID | Room_Number | Capacity |   Status   | Price_perNight |
    1         1             4         Vacant           5 
    1         2             4         Vacant           5  
    1         3             3        Occupied          4
    2         1             4         Vacant           4
    2         2             4        Occupied          4
    3         1             3        Occupied          1
    ..        ..           ..           ..             ..
```

Q:
1. Is this approach valid? (room table doesn't have any primary key, and doesn't need any)

2. Is there any better design?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should have tables for hotels, for rooms, and for occupancy, at least.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment, I have tables for hotels, and for rooms. I don't really need the information about the occupancy -> is the relationship between the 2 tables 'healthy'?  -> All rooms in all of the hotels in unites in one table

Comment: This design will only give you a snapshot in time of the current occupancy. It won't let you handle future bookings (but that may be what you wanted).

Comment: There is no problem at all with having all rooms in one table. Well, it's the rooms table, where else would you want to store the rooms? It's the best solution I can actually think of.

Answer (score 3):

> `room` table doesn't have any primary key, and doesn't need any

Assuming that there would be other tables, such as `reservation` and `occupancy` that reference rows in the `room` table, you do need a primary key. The `room` table does have a nice primary key candidate - a composite key `(Hotel_ID, Room_Number)`. Other tables that reference a room would be able to store `Hotel_ID` and `Room_Number` in order to identify the room being reserved.

> Is there any better design?

You would be better off providing `Room_ID` instead, which could be unique in the `room` table, or only within the same `Hotel_ID`, which would let you change `Room_Number` independently of the `Room_ID`.

For example, imagine that one of your hotels has three floors. Rooms 1, 2, and 3 are on the first floor, rooms 4, 5, 6, and 7 are on the second floor, and rooms 8, 9, 10, and 11 are on the third floor. If you decide to renumber the rooms as follows

```
floor old new
----- --- ---
    1   1 101
    1   2 102
    1   3 103
    2   4 201
    2   5 202
    2   6 203
    2   7 204
    3   8 301
    3   9 302
    3  10 303
    3  11 304
```

a table design with `Room_ID` would let you do that very easily, while your current design would give you hard time fixing the existing data.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like a straight forward one to many relationship between hotel and rooms

room table already has a primary key (composite key) if you take (Hotel_ID, Room_Number) into account

btw you can avoid using a composite key altogether if just give rooms a id(primary key)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already a room is identified by Hotel_ID + Room_Number, so this would make a great primary key. (You *could* add a technical ID, and you could make this the primary key, but keep in mind that this is additional, you would still create a unique constraint on Hotel_ID + Room_Number).

As to designing tables, think of entities. Would every room have its own price? Usually not. You would rather have categories, say "basic", "elegant", "luxury" for a hotel and these have prices. Once the luxury price changes, all luxury rooms get the same altered price. This may even be combined with seasons.

Others have mentioned already that you should have an occupation or bookings table, too. Otherwise: How would you know when a room is available?